# Build2 analog of CMake's find_package

Tags: cmake, package-managers, build-system, build2

Is there are any mechanism in [Build2](https://build2.org) like CMake's find_package?

How to can i include a library that exists only on my system and not in package manager packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use **foo** as dependency in your **bar** project, you need to add a line:

```
cxx.libs += -lfoo
```

in ~/bar/bar/buildfile