# How to use c++20 modules with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20, c++-modules

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) and [MSVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx) already supports [Modules TS](https://github.com/cplusplus/modules-ts) from unfinished C++20 standard.
Can I build my modules based project with CMake or other build system and how?

I tried [build2](https://build2.org/), it supports modules and it works very well, but i have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296089/build2-analog-of-cmakes-find-package) about it's dependency management (UPD: question is closed).

Comment: You can likely use a combination of setting [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), and a CMake if-statement to check for Clang or MSVC, then adding the appropriate compiler flags based on your compiler.

Comment: I tried to compile using Clang with `-std=c++2a -fmodules-ts` and it says **fatal error: module 'VulkanRender' not found**. How can i tell clang where my modules are stored?

Comment: I tried build2 again and I answered my question. Everything works excellent!

Comment: I have the CMake project example with C++ modules.

Works with GCC.

https://github.com/bravikov/cmake-cpp-modules-example

Comment: You can also try xmake, it supports modules and headerunits too. https://github.com/xmake-io/xmake/tree/master/tests/projects/c%2B%2B/modules

Answer (score 55):

*CMake added support for C++20 named modules [in version 3.28](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.28.html#languages)*.

### A complete working example

You can try this example in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Ea54d1Ta3) and find it on [Github](https://github.com/ComicSansMS/CMake_Modules).

```c++
// a.cppm
module;

#include <iostream>

export module MyModule;

int hidden() {
    return 42;
}

export void printMessage() {
    std::cout << "The hidden value is " << hidden() << "\n";
}
```

```c++
// main.cpp
import MyModule;

int main() {
    printMessage();
}
```

```cmake
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(modules-example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(demo)
target_sources(demo
    PUBLIC
    main.cpp
)
target_sources(demo
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET all_my_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    a.cppm
)
```

The project should build fine and rebuild correctly when changing the source files.

## Further details

Note that supporting modules requires far more support from the build system than inserting a new compiler option. It fundamentally changes how dependencies between source files have to be handled during the build: In a pre-modules world all cpp source files can be built independently in any order. With modules that is no longer true, which has implications not only for CMake itself, but also for the downstream build system.

Take a look at the [CMake Fortran modules paper](https://mathstuf.fedorapeople.org/fortran-modules/fortran-modules.html) for the gory details. From a build system's point of view, Fortran's modules behave very similar to the C++20 modules.

### Prerequisites

Ensure that your compiler has proper support for C++20 modules and dependency scanning:

- MSVC compiler version 19.34 or newer
- LLVM/Clang version 16 or newer. (I personally recommend at least version 17 due to a number of bugs in 16)
- gcc version 14 or newer.

Also be aware that CMake only supports modules for the following generators:

- Visual Studio 2022, toolset 19.34 (Visual Studio 17.4) or newer
- Ninja version 1.11 or newer

Be sure that *both* your compiler and build system are sufficiently up-to-date!

### Some General Remarks

- Always use the absolute latest CMake, build tool, and compiler versions that you can. This feature is still under heavy development and receives a constant stream of vital bugfixes.
- Read the docs:

  - [CMake cxxmodules page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-cxxmodules.7.html) documents the limitations of the current implementation in CMake. If something doesn't work as expected, check here first.
  - [D1483](https://mathstuf.fedorapeople.org/fortran-modules/fortran-modules.html) explains how the build process looks like for modules and why it's considerably more difficult than a non-modules build.
  - Familiarize yourself with the basic feature set and vocabulary of Modules. [Daniela Engert's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kqo-jIq4V3I) is an excellent introduction. I also gave [a talk at CppCon 2023 that is aimed at people starting out with modules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x9K9_q2ZXE).
  - Read [Kitware's blog post](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-c20-modules/) for additional info not covered in this answer, like how to try out Modules with a custom build of gcc.
- The tooling will produce [a bunch of `.json` files](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1689r5.html) during the build, which contain the data used by the build system to track module dependencies. If something doesn't work as expected, these can be very useful for debugging.
- This feature is still in an early stage, so be prepared to encounter bugs in both the compiler and build system implementations.

### Using Modules

Module source files need to be specified using the [`FILE_SET` feature of CMake's `target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#file-sets) command. `FILE_SET` is quite useful for libraries without modules as well, so check it out if you don't know the feature yet.

Module source files are distinguished from normal source files by being part of the special `CXX_MODULES` file set:

```
add_executable(my_app)
target_sources(my_app PRIVATE
  FILE_SET all_my_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES
  BASE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  FILES
    a.cppm
    b.cppm
)
target_sources(my_app PRIVATE
  main.cpp
)
```

Here `a.cppm` and `b.cppm` are module source files that can make use of the `export` keyword of C++20 modules. In contrast `main.cpp` may use the `import` keyword, but not the `export` keyword. The distinguishing factor here is the `FILE_SET`, not the file extension! We simply use `.cppm` for module sources here for illustrative purposes.

Note that if your source file is a module *implementation unit* it must *not* be part of the `CXX_MODULES` fileset! You should also not use a module-style file extension like `.cppm` or `.ixx`, but instead use plain `.cpp` as the file extension for these, as some compilers may otherwise treat the files as module interface units, which will break your build.

### Limitations

Header units are currently not supported anywhere (neither by CMake nor by any of the major build systems) and there are serious concerns about the implementability of this feature. Daniel Ruoso gave an [excellent talk at C++Now 2023](https://schedule.cppnow.org/session/c-modules-the-challenges-of-implementing-header-units/) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LGR0U5Opdg)) explaining those concerns. You should stick with named modules for now.

Comment: Did anything change in the last 18 month?

Comment: @Lothar MSVC is now shipping a much more capable Modules implementation than before on version 16.8 and higher. However, this version is currently still in preview and not available on the main release channel. It is also unclear at the moment, whether that implementation already provides everything that would be needed for a proper build system integration with CMake. In general, due to the deep impact of the feature  for the overall build process, I expect it will take a couple of more years (!) before this issue is resolved to a level where you can use it for a productive code base.

Comment: So now 3 and a half years later there is still no support for modules and everything is still experimental (based on https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18355) . So sad.

Comment: The CppCon channel just released [a talk of one of the Kitware founders](https://youtu.be/5X803cXe02Y) sharing an update on C++20 modules support. Basically: it's coming.

Comment: Does the last part - "Original answer" - have any value except historical one? If no, then it could be safely removed: the edit history already incorporates that info.

Comment: But your first part is titled "Experimental Modules Support" and you intend to update it regularly. It looks like the better place for the issue link and explanations why modules support is currently experimental.

Comment: Note that as of 1st June 2023, the `CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP` flag is not necessary anymore and got removed from CMake [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/0183e1bca379199949210217869c3a214702eba1).

Comment: (Note that at least that's the date the commit was pushed, don't know in which CMake version this will be reflected).

Comment: With Ninja 1.10.0, I get an error suggesting that "Ninja 1.11 or higher is required" ("The Ninja generator does not support C++20 modules using Ninja version 1.10.0 due to lack of required features.")

Comment: This config doesn't quite work for me, unfortunately.

If I add in `add_compile_options(-fmodules)` it stops failing saying it can't find the module, though unfortunately then `clang-scan-deps` shits the bed (total crash with a stack dump) unless I also add in `add_compile_options(-fno-implicit-module-maps)`...

I honestly don't really know the ramifications of doing this, and information around it seems scant and arcane and even contradictory, but it does appear to work with at least this kind of very minimal test.

Comment: Note: regarding Clang 17, clang-scan-deps is required but on Macs, I can't find it on Macports. Not sure with Homebrew.

Comment: sorry for a dumb question, but how do you get gcc 14, currently latest is 13.2: https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov gcc 14 has not been released at the time of this writing, but you can compile the current gcc 14 development branch from source on your own to get a working compiler with all the relevant features. That's obviously not a great idea for production environments, but if you want to start playing around with the feature already, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 26):

This works on Linux Manjaro (same as Arch), but should work on any Unix OS. Of course, you need to build with new clang (tested with clang-10).

helloworld.cpp:

```
export module helloworld;
import <cstdio>;
export void hello() { puts("Hello world!"); }
```

main.cpp:

```
import helloworld;  // import declaration

int main() {
    hello();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules)

function(add_module name)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH})
    add_custom_target(${name}.pcm
            COMMAND
                ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
                -std=c++20
                -stdlib=libc++
                -fmodules
                -c
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${ARGN}
                -Xclang -emit-module-interface
                -o ${PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH}/${name}.pcm

            )
endfunction()


add_compile_options(-fmodules)
add_compile_options(-stdlib=libc++)
add_compile_options(-fbuiltin-module-map)
add_compile_options(-fimplicit-module-maps)
add_compile_options(-fprebuilt-module-path=${PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH})

add_module(helloworld helloworld.cpp)
add_executable(main
        main.cpp
        helloworld.cpp
        )
add_dependencies(main helloworld.pcm)
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `helloworld.cpp` to sources of the `main` executable?

Comment: You need to create object file (.o) for that cpp, and link together with other object files.

Comment: with CMake you could probably add another function, which will create OBJECT library from module cpp file(s), and add them to executable, but that's out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Tried on Manjaro with Clang 13 and this is the result:
`C++20 ‘import’ only available with ‘-fmodules-ts’, which is not yet enabled with ‘-std=c++20’`
Also, -stdlibm -fmodules and -Xclang are unrecognized compiler options

Comment: For anyone curious about it working with JetBrains' Clion, the code compiles and runs using the above recipe on my M1 Mac (using homebrew llvm), but Clion can't make sense of the modules and it lints everywhere. It's a known issue though.

Comment: How to split module interface and implementation?  @warchantua

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that you're using gcc 11 with a Makefile generator, the following code should work even without CMake support for C++20:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19) # Lower versions should also be supported
project(cpp20-modules)

# Add target to build iostream module
add_custom_target(std_modules ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Building standard library modules"
    COMMAND g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -c -x c++-system-header iostream
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Function to set up modules in GCC
function (prepare_for_module TGT)
    target_compile_options(${TGT} PUBLIC -fmodules-ts)
    set_property(TARGET ${TGT} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
    set_property(TARGET ${TGT} PROPERTY CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
    add_dependencies(${TGT} std_modules)
endfunction()

# Program name and sources
set (TARGET prog)
set (SOURCES main.cpp)
set (MODULES mymod.cpp)

# Setup program modules object library
set (MODULE_TARGET prog-modules)
add_library(${MODULE_TARGET} OBJECT ${MODULES})
prepare_for_module(${MODULE_TARGET})

# Setup executable
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES})
prepare_for_module(${TARGET})

# Add modules to application using object library
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${MODULE_TARGET})
```

Some explanation:

1. A custom target is added to build the standard library modules, in case you want to include standard library header units (search for "Standard Library Header Units" [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html)). For simplicity, I just added `iostream` here.
2. Next, a function is added to conveniently enable C++20 and Modules TS for targets
3. We first create an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/add_library.html?highlight=object%20library#object-libraries) to build the user modules
4. Finally, we create our executable and link it to the object library created in the previous step.

Not consider the following `main.cpp`:

```cpp
import mymod;

int main() {
    helloModule();
}
```

and `mymod.cpp`:

```cpp
module;
export module mymod;

import <iostream>;

export void helloModule() {
    std::cout << "Hello module!\n";
}
```

Using the above `CMakeLists.txt`, your example should compile fine (successfully tested in Ubuntu WSL with gcc 1.11.0).

**Update:**
Sometimes when changing the `CMakeLists.txt` and recompiling, you may encounter an error

```
error: import "/usr/include/c++/11/iostream" has CRC mismatch
```

Probably the reason is that every new module will attempt to build the standard library modules, but I'm not sure. Unfortunately I didn't find a proper solution to this (avoiding rebuild if the `gcm.cache` directory already exists is bad if you want to add new standard modules, and doing it per-module is a maintenance nightmare). My Q&D solution is to delete `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gcm.cache` and rebuild the modules. I'm happy for better suggestions though.

Comment: Worth to add: it works with makefiles generator, and does NOT work with nonja - error "inputs may not also have inputs" shows.

Comment: About the header units & CRC mismatch problem: You can make a large header  unit with `-fmodule-header` (call it "std.h" or something) that includes all the standard library and import it instead of the regular headers.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Worked flawlessly on Ubuntu 22 with GCC 12.1

Answer (score 4):

CMake ships with experimental support for C++20 modules:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Help/dev/experimental.rst

This is tracked in this issue:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18355

There is also a CMakeCXXModules repository that adds support for modules to CMake.

https://github.com/NTSFka/CMakeCxxModules

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for proper C++20 modules support in CMake, I've found that if using MSVC Windows, for right now you can make-believe it's there by hacking around the build instead of around CMakeLists.txt: continously generate with latest VS generator, and open/build the .sln with VS2020. The IFC dependency chain gets taken care of automatically (`import <iostream>;` just works). Haven't tried Windows clang or cross-compiling. It's not ideal but for now at least another decently workable alternative today, so far.

Important afterthought: use .cppm and .ixx extensions.

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 Modules the file compilation order matters, which is totally new. That's why the implementation is complicated and still experimental in 2023. Please read the authors [blogpost](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-c20-modules/)

Comment: Not really an answer to the question. But helpful still.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find Cmake support for modules. Here is an example how to use modules using clang. I am using Mac and this example works ok on my system. It took me quite a while to figure this out so unsure how general this is across linux or Windows.

Source code in file driver.cxx

```
import hello;
int main() { say_hello("Modules"); }
```

Source code in file hello.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
module hello;
void say_hello(const char *n) {
  std::cout << "Hello, " << n << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

Source code in file hello.mxx

```
export module hello;
export void say_hello (const char* name);
```

And to compile the code with above source files, here are command lines on terminal

```
clang++ \
  -std=c++2a                        \
  -fmodules-ts                      \
  --precompile                      \
  -x c++-module                     \
  -Xclang -fmodules-embed-all-files \
  -Xclang -fmodules-codegen         \
  -Xclang -fmodules-debuginfo       \
  -o hello.pcm hello.mxx

clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -o hello.pcm.o -c hello.pcm

clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -x c++ -o hello.o \
  -fmodule-file=hello.pcm -c hello.cxx

clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -x c++ -o driver.o \
  -fmodule-file=hello=hello.pcm -c driver.cxx

clang++ -o hello hello.pcm.o driver.o hello.o
```

and to get clean start on next compile

```
rm -f *.o
rm -f hello
rm -f hello.pcm
```

expected output

```
./hello
Hello, Modules!
```

Hope this helps, all the best.

Comment: This is a nice answer - but not for this question. You might consider formulating a question ("Simple example of building a C++ program using a module?") modules and posting it with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

CMake does not currently support C++20 modules like the others have stated. However, module support for Fortran is very similar, and perhaps this could be easily changed to support modules in C++20.

http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Build+tools

Now, perhaps there i an easy way to modify this to support C++20 directly. Not sure. It is worth exploring and doing a pull request should you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Add MSVC version (revised from @warchantua 's answer):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Cpp20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules)
set(STD_MODULES_DIR "D:/MSVC/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/ifc/x64") # macro "$(VC_IFCPath)" in MSVC

function(add_module name)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR})
    add_custom_target(${name}.ifc
            COMMAND
                ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
                /std:c++latest
                /stdIfcDir ${STD_MODULES_DIR}
                /experimental:module
                /c
                /EHsc
                /MD
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${ARGN}
                /module:export
                /ifcOutput
                ${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR}/${name}.ifc
                /Fo${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR}/${name}.obj
            )
endfunction()

set(CUSTOM_MODULES_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules)
add_module(my_module ${CUSTOM_MODULES_DIR}/my_module.ixx)

add_executable(test
    test.cpp
    )
target_compile_options(test
    BEFORE
    PRIVATE
    /std:c++latest
    /experimental:module
    /stdIfcDir ${STD_MODULES_DIR}
    /ifcSearchDir ${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR}
    /reference my_module=${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR}/my_module.ifc
    /EHsc
    /MD
)
target_link_libraries(test ${PREBUILT_MODULE_DIR}/my_module.obj)
add_dependencies(test my_module.ifc)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you set up your files in your directory?

I am following your CMakeLists and getting weirdo MSVC 2022 compiler errors, like not founding de `STD_MODULES_DIR` and use of `/module:export` requires `/experimental:module` which is already on the CMake file!

Comment: The `STD_MODULES_DIR` is required only if you use the standard library modules in your project (e.g.`std.core`), if you use the `#include` directives, no need use add this dir and `stdIfcDir` compile option.

Comment: Maybe you'd better try with modules in command line first ([this is a good tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-cpp-modules-in-msvc-from-the-command-line-part-1/)), my demo CMakeLists is just wrapped command line cmds into cmake.

Comment: I deleted /stdIfcDir and /ifcSearchDir and works perfectly. Also I can use import `std.core` or whatever without those compile options, which aren't working for me. 

I am using the 2022 MSVC compiler, but as I said, now I can fully compile my project