# How to use CMake to build a project with C++23 standard library module(import std)?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++-modules, c++23

As we know, C++23 support Standard Library Modules. Until May 2023, MSVC support it but we need add Standard Library Modules manually as [Microsoft blog mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170).

But how to use `import std` in CMake project? The MS blog doesn't mentioned it. And these files can't work.(The `std.ifc` file is obtained from microsoft blog tutorial:`cl /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd /c "%VCToolsInstallDir%\modules\std.ixx"`(use in msvc x64 native console))

**CMakeList.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.26)

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP ON)

set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

project(1-1)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    FILE_SET all_my_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    main.cpp
    std.ifc
)
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
import std;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello\n";
}
```

And MSVC shows:

```bash
[build] main.cpp(1,11): error C2230: Could not find module "std" 
[build] main.cpp(5,5): error C2065: "cout" : Undeclared identifier
```

I can use copy `%VCToolsInstallDir\modules\std.ixx` to project folder and change `std.ifc` to `std.ixx`, but is there a more elegant way to achieve it to avoid building std module every time? I think it's because `.ifc` is not a source file,how to deal with it in CMake?

Comment: What is the problem you get with the `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp` files you show? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the std module can't find. I add it in question now.

Comment: "*But how to use import std.io in CMake project?*" You don't. `std.io` is not a C++23 module. There are `std` and `std.compat`; that's it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry for wrong expression, I just want to ask `std`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Visual Studio keeps changing how this works, I will try and update the answer as things progress.

As a prerequisite you need to set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to use C++23:

```cmake
[...]
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(demo)
target_sources(demo
  PRIVATE
    demo.cpp
)
```

This will set the VS configuration property `C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard` to `/std:c++latest`. Visual Studio 17.6 now also provides a property `C/C++->Language->Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules` which needs to be to `Yes` and will then automatically build the standard library modules on `/std:c++latest` as part of your project build.

This option used to be activated by default, but Visual Studio recently changed that default to `No`, so you now need to activate that option manually. CMake is currently [considering to provide an option for controlling this property](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24922).

For older versions of Visual Studio, you will have to compile the `std` named module *yourself* before importing it.

Since CMake does not support importing pre-compiled modules at the moment, the easiest way to get things running is therefore to simply include the primary module interface for the standard library in your project.

Be sure to first read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244367/577603) to understand the current prerequisites and limitations of the C++20 modules in CMake.

CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
[...]
add_executable(demo)

file(COPY
  # you don't want to hardcode the path here in a real-world project,
  # but you get the idea
  "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/modules/std.ixx"
  DESTINATION
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/stdxx
)

target_sources(demo
  PRIVATE
  FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/stdxx/std.ixx
  PRIVATE
  demo.cpp
)
```

demo.cpp

```c++
import std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

CMake rightfully prevents you from including module sources outside of your source tree in the build. So we will copy the module interface file to our binary tree for building.

As usual, having the same primary module interface appear more than once in a program is not allowed. Structure your build accordingly so that you don't accidentally end up with `std.ixx` being compiled twice.

Comment: Could I understand there is no method to use pre-compiled module in cmake now?

Comment: @LeenHawk That is correct. There's still a couple of unresolved issues in that area that tooling vendors will need to figure out. See e.g. [P2577](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2577r2.pdf) for details. Build2 already supports this through a proprietary metadata file format (which then also only works for build2, naturally), but all the other build systems will likely depend on SG15 to release a standardized format before supporting this.

Comment: @LeenHawk And finally, as suspected, the whole endeavour just became a lot easier with the last Visual Studio update. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Dear sir, do you know hot to use c++20 modules with cmake 3.28 and msvc? It seems there are some breaking changes between cmake 3.27 and 3.28 and msvc couldn't found std module again...

Comment: Came here just to ask for the same. I tried CMake 3.28-rc4 with both Ninja and MSVC2022 generators, but `import std` didn't work

Comment: @LeenHawk Visual Studio keeps changing the defaults here. I will try and keep this answer updated, but be aware that whatever method you are using right now will probably keep breaking frequently with updates in the near future.

Comment: @ComicSansMS A very fair assumption to make on the Windows + MSVC toolchain (both on development and CI platforms) is that the environment is pre-loaded with `vcvarsall.bat`. Then, we may use `"$ENV{VCTOOLSINSTALLDIR}\modules\std.ixx"` instead of hard-coding the entire path.