# How to do `import std` with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, c++23

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76274172/14190718) and [CMake 3.28](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.28.html), we should be able to `import std`
without any extra effort.
But I'm getting the error `Module 'std' not found` with following simple demo.

```
import std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(module_tst)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(demo)
target_sources(demo
    PRIVATE
    main.cpp
)
```

`import std` works well in Visual Studio, as long as I checked `C/C++ -> General -> Scan Sources for Module Dependencies`. I found something similar in cmake document that is `CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES` but set it on makes no difference. Is there anything missing?

I'm using latest cmake 3.28 rc1 and VS 17.8.0 Preview 4.0

Comment: Not directly related, but it is useful to specify this too: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)` just to catch cases when your compiler actually don't support requested standard.

Comment: The following open cmake issue is probably related to this question: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24922.
The options to "build STL modules" and "scan source for module dependencies" can currently not be enabled directly via cmake settings. The defaults for these settings have changed at least once between Visual Studio versions.
A potential workaround suggested in the issue discussion is to create a VS property sheet configuring these settings that is then added in cmake as a VS_USER_PROPS property. There is an example in the thread.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268455/how-to-use-cmake-to-build-a-project-with-c23-standard-library-moduleimport-st?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1):

After I did tried c++ module for few month.
As far as I knew (for MSVC only).

- `import std` was changed to `import std.core` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#enable-modules-in-the-microsoft-c-compiler).
- We must install `c++ module for MSVC` component. It wasn't selected by default. You could install them by goto Visual Studio Installer > Modify.
- Module partition doesn't work with Ninja generator.
- Must add `/experimental:module` when complie command even document say "enabled automatically by either /std:c++20 or /std:c++latest" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/experimental-module?view=msvc-170).
- I still don't know how to make intellisense working with `import std.core` yet.

here my boilerplate.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.26)

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a") #this require to enable c++ module feature in my cmake version
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP 1) # enable scan dependencies /scanDependencies
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) # it work with c++20 but has some warnning

project ("cmake_project")

add_compile_options(
   /EHsc 
   /experimental:module # require
   $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/O2>
)

add_library(my_lib)
target_sources(my_lib PUBLIC FILE_SET my_lib_fs TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES 
    "src/modules/ratt.ixx"
)# compile as c++ module

add_executable (main "src/main.cpp" )
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE my_lib)
```

Comment: `std.core` is a discontinued experiment, and you're looking at/linking to outdated docs. `import std` was not changed to `import std.core`, _quite_ the opposite

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you. You a help me a lot to proof what i knew it's wrong.